# Identity for $L(s,\chi)L(s,\bar\chi)$

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta

I was told recently that there is an identity roughly of the form

$$L(s,\chi)L(s,\bar\chi)=\zeta(s)^2$$

If true, it seems like there should be a short proof of this. Could someone supply a reference, and/or the proof of this?

Comment: This cannot be true. For $s=1$ the LHS is finite, but the RHS is not. The following [MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25794/shortest-most-elegant-proof-for-l1-chi-neq-0) might be helpful, perhaps.

Comment: Ah, 'obviously'. This answers my question. I wish I could accept this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether this identity is the one you were told recently. 
It cannot be true, because for $s=1$ the LHS is finite, but the RHS is not. 
However we have a *functional equation* for $L$-series, of the form
$$
L(s,\chi)=\epsilon(\chi)L(1-s,\overline{\chi}),
$$
which one can find in several books on analytic number theory. Also studied is the product over all Dirichlet characters, the Dedekind zeta function
$$
\prod_{\chi \bmod N}L(s,\chi).
$$